# /etc/hosts read-only with root user login

Tags: hosts, read-only

I am using Debian Server 9.5 I can't change my /etc/hosts file, its being read-only

```
ls -lh /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    461 Jan  6  2021 hosts
```

and I am ssh via root user

Comment: Maybe the file system is mounted as read-only? How did you determine the hosts file is actually read-only and how did you verify you have root access?

Comment: From a terminal, do `sudo <editor> <filename>`. Does it work for `hosts`?

Comment: Those perms say its read-write for root.